# Remove old emblems from previous Nautilus version

Tags: nautilus, uninstall, emblem

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, and I'd like to remove the emblems I put on certain folders from the previous menu of nautilus.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, to solve my problem, I erased all files from the folder :

```
~/.local/shared/gvfs-metadata
```

Cf. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+question/93098

Comment: didn't work for me even loging out and back in to restart.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of questions which are in some way duplicates of this one but none of them, including this one had an answer that worked for me. I did however discover a way to remove the carry over emblems from 11.04. I rename the folder and create a new folder with the original name. Finally I move the folder contents to from the old folder to the new one and delete the old folder with it's emblems. Perhaps not elegant but it does work. The only gotcha is that if any folders or files that were synced with Ubuntu One need to be re-established. When you look in Ubuntu One your synced files will now be grayed out. Recheck each individually and accept that the files will be merged without creating duplicates. And you're done.